# Duplicate data of a ROW of a datagridview into another

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, indexing

I need to REPLICATE a SINGLE row from a datagridview(grid_display) into another datagridview(grid_detail)

I could replicate the column headers.like below.

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in grid_display.Columns)
{
    grid_detail.Columns.Add(c.Clone() as DataGridViewColumn);

}

//then you can copy the rows values one by one (working on the selectedrows collection)
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in grid_display.SelectedRows)
{
    int index = grid_detail.Rows.Add(r.Clone() as DataGridViewRow);
    foreach (DataGridViewCell o in r.Cells)
    {
        grid_detail.Rows[index].Cells[o.ColumnIndex].Value = o.Value;
    }
}
```

How do i replicate the DATA of A SINGLE selected row from grid_display to grid_detail ?

Comment: Where are you calling this code?